# Highstocks Flags (Combine the flags into single flag if the day have more than one flag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLL7.jpg)
 I want to show the single flag instead of showing multiple flags in Highstocks (if the day have more than announcements for a company).If i click on that flag the tooltip will show the announcement list one by one i can able to click on the each announcement to show the full annoucement

Like this i want the result.Can anyone please help me.
http://investors.aflac.com/stock-information/interactive-chart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **data grouping** is not implemented for `flags` series (although it exists in the API for this type of series). It can be easily programmed though:

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/jmLnm4gk/

The algorithm searches for the subsequent points with the same x value and merges them into one (group property is created which is later used in the tooltip):

```
  load: function() {
      var series = this.series[1],
        points = series.points,
        group = [];


      for (var i = points.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        var p = points[i],
          nextP = points[i + 1]

        // two points with same x values
        if (p.x === nextP.x) {

          // copy the group if it already exists in next point
          if (nextP.group) {
            p.group = nextP.group;
          } else { // create a new group
            p.group = [nextP.options];
          }

          // add point's options to its group
          p.group.push(p.options);

          // remove previous point
          nextP.remove(false);

          // change text displayed on flag
          p.update({
            title: 'Grouped flags'
          }, false);

        } // end of if
      } // end of for
      this.redraw();
    } // end of function

(...)

  plotOptions: {
    flags: {
      tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
          return this.group ? this.group.reduce((acc, val) => val.text + ' ' + acc, '') : this.text;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```